# How should the forever function be used?

Tags: haskell

I have a function. Let's say it looks like this:

```
strangeFunc = do
  putStrLn "Welcome to the game! Please, enter the name of the file: "
 --some more code
```

Then, I want it to run forever, so I do this

```
strangeFunc = forever $ do
  putStrLn "Welcome to the game! Please, enter the name of the file: "
  --some more code
```

But I have an error: `variable not in scope: forever`. How can I fix it?

Comment: A side note: `forever` is not a monad, it is a function.

Comment: Your example has no variables, so we don't know why there's a variable out of scope. That just means you're referring to some variable that is unknown (in that context).

Comment: Also while you can use `forever`, if running something forever is confusing you this much, maybe you should be trying to do it without resorting to `forever` first, for instructional purposes. All you need is to code an "infinite loop", i.e. write a function that "runs the code" then calls itself.

Answer (score 8):

You must import `forever` from `Control.Monad`. Add this to the top of your file:

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
```

When the compiler says `variable not in scope...`, it means "I don't know what this is supposed to be; you haven't defined it." This can be caused by not having the required modules imported.

How did I know this? If you [search for `forever` on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=forever), it says that it is in the `Control.Monad` module, in the `base` package. Hence, you must import it in order to use it.